# Importar dados utilizando o pacote xlsx

Tags: javascript

Olá

As vezes existe a necessidade de se importar arquivo excel para a base de dados afim de se pegar um atalho para evitar inserts um a um

Sendo assim, fiz um função em Vue.js que importa uma planilha do excel

```
import xlsx from 'xlsx'
importExcel(e) {
            this.$emit('buscando', true)
            const files = e.target.files;            
            if (!files.length) {
                return ;
            } else if (!/\.(xls|xlsx)$/.test(files[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                return alert("The upload format is incorrect. Please upload xls or xlsx format");
            }
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = async ev => {
                try {
                    const data = ev.target.result;
                    const XLSX = xlsx;
                    const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                        type: "binary"
                    });
                    const wsname = workbook.SheetNames[0]; // Take the first sheet，wb.SheetNames[0] :Take the name of the first sheet in the sheets
                    const ws = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[wsname]); // Generate JSON table content，wb.Sheets[Sheet名]    Get the data of the first sheet

                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < ws.length; i++) {        
                         const campoData = ws[i]['DATA INÍCIO']
                     }   // fim for

                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('erro',e);
                    return alert(`Houve um problema na importação. Verifique as colunas e tente novamente`);;
                }
            };
            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
            var input = document.getElementById("upload");
            input.value = "";
```

Qual a dificuldade?

É no campo data:

Por exemplo: 01/01/2021

Quando leio o arquivo excel ele esta data de exemplo vem em um formato inteiro: '44197' por exemplo

Como faço para ler exatamente o que tem na célula e não essa transformação que o próprio excel faz?

A biblioteca que estou utilizando é a [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Answer (score -3):

So precisas adicionar  isso no workbook   `const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary",cellDates: true, dateNF: 'yyyy/mm/dd;@' });`